How to get a unique list of all primary keys from a dynamo db table?
I'm running a scan on a table and it comes across the same PK multiple times. As advertised, it's not very efficient.
I read somewhere that if I create a GSI on the PK and sort key that when I scan the index, it will be a unique list.
Before I try this out, does anybody know if that is the case?

No that's not the case, let me share a blog with you that does exactly what you need using a Scan. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/generate-a-distinct-set-of-partition-keys-for-an-amazon-dynamodb-table-efficiently/ Essentially you loop over every item collection in the table obtaining the first item in each.
